# How to make generic Stylus mixins for a certain prefix?

Tags: css, stylus

I'm currently using Stylus to get around vendor specific CSS properties:

```
vendor(prop, args)
    -webkit-{prop} args
    -moz-{prop} args
    -ms-{prop} args
    -o-{prop} args
    {prop} args

animation()
    vendor('animation', arguments)
```

However, this works only for `animation`, but not for `animation-name` or `animation-duration`.

Is there a way to create a mixin for any `animation-*`, regardless of the end of the property name?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/visionmedia/nib. they do some of this automatically for you, but not all.

Comment: This is a few years old, but for people stumbling upon it now, I recommend autoprefixer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into the nib — it provides a bunch of mixins that make everything right.

Currently there is no way to achieve what you wish, so if you'd still like to stick with your own mixins, it would be only a copy-and-paste work to create all those mixins like `animation-name()` etc.